# How do you make RStudio remember R installations it used in the past?

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I use a separate installation of R for each project.
To make RStudio use the right one I click and hold down the Control key when I start RStudio.
This opens a "Choosing R Installation" pop-up where I can select the R binary I need.

The problem is that - unlike in [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop) RStudio support article - the pop-up shows only the very last version of R that I used.
So whenever I switch projects I have to browse to the R binary that I need.

Is there a way to make RStudio remember the other R versions I've used?

If there isn't, where does RStudio look for the last used one? If I knew that, I could probably use a script to overwrite it before launching RStudio.

Some details:

- I am on Windows 7/10.
- RStudio version is 1.3.1093
- None of the registry keys described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Does-R-use-the-Registry_003f) are set.

Comment: I believe RStudio just uses whichever version of R that was last used when you open the software.

Comment: @Phil, thanks for commenting. RStudio instructions (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop) on using different R versions have a screenshot that contains multiple options to choose from. This might have changed in some RStudio update, or maybe the screenshot was not actually taken on Windows. So you might be right, of course. In this case, I would like to know where RStudio stores the information about the last used version of R - I could then just overwrite it.

Comment: I think filing an issue on RStudio's GH repo would be the most efficient way of finding out.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, @Phil! RStudio's GitHub issue tracker suggested that questions should be asked at RStudio Community - which is what I did. Here is the link if anyone is interested: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-make-rstudio-remember-r-installations-it-used-in-the-past/89041

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you kept the registry clean and under the assumption that you are using distinct/separate folders for each of your projects one COULD be tempted to try something like

- a `.Renviron` file containing  `R_HOME=C:/path/to/your/required/version` or
- a `.Rprofile` file containing `Sys.setenv(R_HOME='path/to/your/version')`

in your project folder(s)?
Or potentially put a .bat file in there with content like

```
SET R_HOME=Path/to/your/R.version
cd /D "%~dp0"
start .YourProject.Rproj
```

BUT NOPE!
Currently this type of functionality/behaviour is NOT available for RStudio Desktop Free (as of time of writing this is RStudio Desktop 1.3.1093) BUT can only be achieved with RStudio Server PRO - see [6.3.3 User Configurable Default Version](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/1.3.820-1/r-versions.html#configuring-the-default-version-of-r).

@Evgenil: updated answer based on your suggestion and after I had the time to test the idea as well

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @GWD. I'll try this today.

Comment: The `.Renviron` solution did not work. `R.home()` returns the path specified in the `.Renviron` file but it is not where r sessions are started from. Both looking into the RStudio options and using `R.Version()` show that it is the last r version that is still being used. I think your answer should be updated with this information because it might *look* like it worked while it actually doesn't. I don't meat to be ungrateful, I just worry about other people using your answer without checking.

Comment: Setting `R_HOME` in the terminal has the same effect (`R.home()` is changed but not which R binary is used).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The way I solved this was by utilizing portable versions of R and RStudio.

To get this to work I needed a few things.

- Download portable versions of R, https://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/files/
- Download portable versions of RStudio, https://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/files/
- Download IniFile 1.92, https://www.horstmuc.de/wbat32.htm#inifile

In this example I have created three folders on my desktop.

- BatchSetRandRStudio, R-Portable-4.1.2, RStudio-2022.02.3-492

Example steps:

1. Create a folder to house the batch file that will launch R and RStudio. e.g. C:\Users<username>\Desktop\BatchSetRandRStudio.
2. Place the downloaded IniFile, inifile.exe, in the folder you just created for the batch file.
3. Create a batch file with the example code below and change the paths to your specifications for the portable versions of R and RStudio. e.g. Batch4.1.2RLaunchRStudioRun.bat

```
@echo off

REM Remember to update the Rprofile.site within each R-Portable location, in the etc folder for each portable R version:
REM C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\R-Portable-4.1.2\App\R-Portable\etc
REM .First = function(){
REM     .libPaths(.Library)
REM }

REM Also the portable R library location is located:
REM C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\R-Portable-4.1.2\App\R-Portable\library

:: INI editor; inifile.exe needs to be in same folder of batch file to work
:: Source: https://www.horstmuc.de/wbat32.htm#inifile
:: INIFILE filename [section] item=string
:: inifile.exe "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\RStudio\desktop.ini" [General] RBinDir=C:/Users/<username>/Desktop/R-Portable-4.1.2/App/R-Portable/bin/x64
inifile.exe "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\RStudio\desktop.ini" [General] RBinDir=C:/Users/<username>/Desktop/R-Portable-4.1.2/App/R-Portable/bin/x64

:: FOR R 4.1.2
:: Start Program
:: start "" "C:\Users\<project folder>\Desktop\RStudio-2022.02.3-492\bin\rstudio.exe"
start "" "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\RStudio-2022.02.3-492\bin\rstudio.exe"

:: FOR R 4.1.2
:: Start Program and specific project
:: start "" "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\RStudio-2022.02.3-492\bin\rstudio.exe" "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\R-Portable-4.1.2\Projects\<project folder>\<project name>.Rproj" & :: This command starts RStudio and opens specific project
```

4. Update the Rprofile.site file within each R-Portable location (allows one to have separate package installations for each portable version you create) with the following code:

```
.First = function(){
    .libPaths(.Library)
}
```

5. Run the batch file, RStudio should open with the version of R you have pointed it to as well as the version of RStudio you have specified. You should be able to add projects and create specific batch files to open each project separately.